# Setting up pdfpages with memoir?

Tags: memoir, pdfpages

I am using memoir for writing my PhD thesis. In my university we have to include submitted, accepted, and prepared drafts of related papers as appendices.

These papers have all been previously created using LaTeX (using the class elsarticle). I have them as PDF with white borders/margins stripped away using Adobe Acrobat. They are therefore in different sizes.

My question is in regard to pdfpages. How can I make sure that a pdf-page is inserted correctly on a full document-page (without a Chapter-title).

I use the following class-options and predefined layout:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,final,showtrims]{memoir}
\semiisopage[12]
\checkandfixthelayout
```

My problem is that pdfpages seems to center the pdf-page itself on the entire stock (if we use memoir-jargon). I want the pages to center/fit in the area delimited by lengths such as `\textwidth` and `\textheight` (defined in the memoir manual, memman.pdf, on page 10 and 11).

I use the following options with `\includepdf`:

```
\includepdf[
    pages={-},
    frame=false, % so I can adjust this if I need it
    noautoscale=true, % I should scale it myself, right?
    scale=1.0, % is this 1.0 by default?
    pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}, % I guess this is necessary?
    %templatesize={\textwidth}{\textheight}, % not sure this work?
    offset={0mm 0mm} % my guess is, that I need to adjust this one?
]{<paper_pdf_filename>}
```

As I mention above, I would likely need to adjust `offset` so that the pages are placed/fitted in the area called "body" on page 10-11 in the memoir manual.

**Further elaborations:**

I would like the pages of each paper to be part of the surrounding document. The entire thesis will still have material after the inserted papers. It will continue with a global reference section and perhaps even a short index. The inserted pages of each paper should exist as if they are exactly that - inserts - not pages on their own. Which is why I use the pagestyle `plain` to include the thesis page number.

If you take a look at [memman.pdf](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) on page 10-11, you will see the different page-margins for the memoir-class. I need the logic box of each inserted page to have an offset such that is correct in regards to these margins.

I have tried the following (using the calc-package):

```
\newcommand{\pdfxoffset}{\marginparsep + \marginparwidth + \trimedge}
\newcommand{\pdfyoffset}{\uppermargin + \trimtop}
```

With these options for `\includepdf`:

```
pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}},
width=\textwidth,
height=\textheight,
offset={\pdfxoffset mm \pdfyoffset mm}
```

But it does not fit entirely as I want it (but almost). I am also not exactly sure what I am doing here. Can I just add lengths together like this? Not sure I even grasp the programming-language constructs in TeX/LaTeX.

Comment: The fact that `pdfpages` is not affected by the text area is one of its main features IMHO. You can use `\includegraphics[page=..,width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{..}` instead for every page. I recently finished my PhD thesis and I did not use the same text area for the papers in the appendix.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to help if I use `\textwidth`and `\textheight`. If the attempts with the margins fail completely I will use this as a method to fall back to.

Comment: @OleThomsenBuus I think I've figured out most of the offset you need, but a slight difference remains -- maybe someone else can answer this new question: [proper alignment of pdfpages import in memoir typeblock](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59902/proper-alignment-of-pdfpages-import-in-memoir-typeblock)

Comment: @dgs Thanks for the effort though. It seems you have not gotten much feedback on it. The single vote up was from me btw. I can't comment on your question ... and currently I have no answer :) I think I have accepted that each pdf-page gets centered in a page. But this latex-fiddling also a form of procrastination really. Should just write instead.

Comment: Sure, fiddling can be great fun. Concerning the question, I wouldn't preclude the problem's a bug, so there might not even be an answer (thanks for the vote, btw.). However, I'd consider your specific problem as being virtually solved---did you try to add the difference in `\spinemargin`, as described in the other question? The figure there is at 800% magnification, so you might not even notice the remaining gap. Otherwise, just add some manually determined 1.x pt. Or is there anything else you need?

Comment: @dgs If you believe you have found an answer for the offset problem, which you might have (have not tested it yet), then post it below so I can accept it here later.

Comment: @OleThomsenBuus I have---did you give it a try?

Comment: @dgs I will get back to it in a week or two. Then I will try to fiddle with it again. I will leave this open until then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know `memoir` jargon, but if I understood you correctly, you want to insert a PDF that stretches to the normal `\textwidth` on an otherwise empty page. This can be achieved by defining a customized page style (unless redefined, `plain` would include a page number) and using the `\includegraphics` options `width` and `height`, which are passed on by `pdfpages`.

As pointed out by @egreg, with `memoir` and no pagestyle customizations needed, rather `\thispagestyle{empty}` should be used. Further, `graphicx` provides a parameter `keepaspectratio` which ensures that if both width and height of the PDF are specified, it is scaled such that the aspect ratio is kept and neither width nor height are exceeded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{%
    \fancyhf{}%                             %clear headers, footers
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%     %and remove header rule
}

\begin{document}


\includepdf[pages=1,
            pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}}, %is default, only mentioned to show alternative usage of customized mystyle
            width=\textwidth,
            height=\textheight,     
            keepaspectratio,
            frame]{yourfile.pdf}            
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I added some more necessary information in my question above. Not exactly what I needed, but now I know how to create pagestyles ... that's never useless :)

Comment: Why not simply `\thispagestyle{empty}`? Using `fancyhdr` with `memoir` is not really recommended. Also the options `width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio` will make the included PDF not exceed any of the dimension, while not distorting the image.

Comment: @egreg En bref: Not thought of/not known the parameter. Thanks.

Comment: I believe that pdfpages use `\thispagestyle{empty}` in `pagestyle` by default?

Comment: True. I'd nevertheless consider it useful to leave in the customized style definition as an alternative. I'll add a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer*: According to my assumption stated in [proper alignment of pdfpages import in memoir typeblock](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59902/proper-alignment-of-pdfpages-import-in-memoir-typeblock), for `twoside` layout the difference in `\spinemargin` between `oneside` and `twoside` needs to be chosen as the horizontal offset. To find the values of `\spinemargin`, uncomment the `\the` commands (which print the current parameter values) and compile once with `oneside` option and again with `twoside` selected. Note the values and compute the difference. There might be a way to automate this if switching the layout options within the document is feasible; I used a calculator. For reasons yet unknown (cf. the linked question), the computed value needs to be slightly adjusted; I've subtracted `1pt`.

If you want the PDF to be vertically centered within the typeblock, set the vertical offset to zero. Should it be aligned to the top or bottom, the difference between the type area height and the height of the scaled imported PDF needs to be computed. If the imported PDF is an A4 format, the height-to-width ratio is the square root of two. Since the PDF is scaled such that its width equals `\textwidth`, multiplication of `\textwidth` with sqrt(2) yields the scaled height of the imported PDF. The height of the type area is given by `\textheight`. The required offset then is half of the difference of the two heights, either positive or negative for top or bottom alignment. Again, this value needs to be slightly adjusted; I've subtracted `1.68pt`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,final,showtrims]{memoir}%

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{showframe}  %show page geometry

\begin{document}

%   \the\spinemargin \quad      %compute xoffset = \spinemargin(twoside) - \spinemargine(oneside) = -21pt
%   \the\textwidth \quad    
%   \the\textheight         %compute yoffset = .5 (\textheight - scaled-a4paper-height) = 25.18pt, with scaled-a4paper-height = \textwidth * (height(a4paper) / width(a4paper)) = \textwidth * sqrt(2)

\includepdf[pages=1-2,
            pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}},
            width=\textwidth,
            height=\textheight,     
            keepaspectratio,
            offset=-22pt 23.5pt %for vertically centered alignment, set yoffset=0pt
            ]{a4red.pdf}            
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

*While my first answer is concerned with the import parameters, this one is about finding the right `offset` values. One could argue that the question should have been split; anyway, it doesn't seem to make sence to merge the answers.